# Angular sends twice request once modified headers

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have a strange problem with my SAP application, once I modified the headers, every request will become twice, like below

[image]

My structure consists of a restful API and the SAP application, the reason why I want to modify headers is to put a token issued from restful API. The restful API is configured to allow other domains invocations, I know the CORS sends a 'Preflight' request to fetch some information, but why I can't capture duplicate request without header modification, once header modification applied, duplication request appeared.

This is the way I modified my headers in controller,

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['x2-token'] = _TOKEN;
```

Anyone has an idea or a clues? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think modifying headers is causing this. Can you please share code so that we can examine issue.

Comment: I'm sure it's caused by headers modification, once modified angular will send an OPTIONS request to server then another real request, the strangest thing is, once remove the modification this OPTIONS request never be fired.

Comment: should be an OPTIONS request followed by GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH whatever you are trying to do

Comment: @RahulArora yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

After studied a while, I confirmed that the first request of the duplication is a `preflight` request, and that **A custom header will trigger the preflight** over a cross domain invocation, otherwise it can be also triggered by certain Content-Type of your header like `application/json`, if your header was touched by yourself, you can simply set Content-Type to `text/plain` to prevent this problem.